# How to mark a stressed vowel in a text?

Tags: names, typography, stress, diacritics

I write an article containing many Russian names and surnames, and sometimes it is important to specify which vowel is stressed (e.g. to distinguish B**a**skov from Bask**o**v). In Russian we put an accent upon a letter:

> He introduced himself as Nikolay Báskov, though his father always pronounced his own surname as Baskóv.

Is this notation correct in English? If not, how do you suggest to correct this sentence?

Comment: "Correct" or not, I would have no trouble with it as long as it serves a purpose. We see something similar in Spanish names when the accent is not in the usual place, so it doesn't seem odd.

Comment: I think many American English speakers at least would be familiar with the use in Spanish that Jim Mack mentions. I think the most common way of indicating stress would actually be respelling and using capitalization ("he introduced himself as Nikolay Baskov ('BASK-ov') although his father always pronounced his own surname as 'Bas-KOV'"). But that might look too informal for an article.

Comment: Probably the accented vowel is best. Other options include boldface (***Bas**kov* vs *Bas**kov***) or capitals (_BASkov_ vs _BasKOV_, which is less than satisfactory for capitalized words).

Comment: In English, accents are often used for stressed syllables in analyzing poetry. (And [Gerard Manley Hopkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_Beauty) even added accents to his poetry to show how it should be read.)

Answer (score 1):

Those of us who are familiar with Spanish will have no problem with Báskov and Baskóv.

Unfortunately, because of the irregularity of English spelling there is no foolproof way of ensuring correct pronunciation.

Even if you write BASkov and BasKOV, I can tell you from experience that some people will still not get the emphasis in the right place. That is true even though they will swear they are emphasising the correct syllable!

I suggest you use Báskov and Baskóv and just hope that it will be understood.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that, at least in the U.S. many English speakers are clueless about accents in Spanish, so personally I would favor **Bas**kov, but with the whole syllable in bold, not just the vowel.

Whatever system you end up using, I hope you'll explain to the reader what's going on in a note in the beginning.

In my experience, obtuse English speakers have an easier time getting the hang of pronouncing an unfamiliar name if you provide them with a familiar model that shows the desired stress pattern.  Unless you're extraordinarily lucky, you probably won't be able to find one that rhymes exactly, but that's okay.  For example, for Baskov, you could use *lots of*.  You could do this in sort of a glossary in the beginning or as a footnote to the first occurrence of each name.

By the way, is that last V really what you want, or do you want Baskoff?  If the latter, then the stress model could be *dots off*.

(The two stress models I suggested here need more work, because of the two consonants in the middle -- I included these examples just to give you the idea.)

Great question!

Comment: One does not use inline bold in professionally typeset work because it mangles the page color too badly if you do. It is reserved for headers and ransom notes. Emphasis is denoted via an italic typeface.